# Nginx: avoid nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "index" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Tags: nginx

I have multiple websites (just a static sites) that point to same server. In this server, I am using Nginx. I have multiple configuration files, each config file for each website. For example, here is my sample:

```
server {
   root /var/www/example/build;
   server_name example.com www.example.com
   index index.html index.htm;
   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name example.com www.example.com
   index index.html index.htm;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

When I run following command: `sudo nginx -t` for checking nginx grammar. I meet this warning:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "index" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "index.html" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "index.htm" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "index" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "index.html" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "index.htm" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

I have tested and see that those warnings are not the problem. (because I listen same port on multiple files). But I don't know if I remove listen port in one of those files, are there any problems ? And are there any other ways to disable this warning.

Thanks

Comment: You are missing semicolons after the `server_name` directive. So your following `index` line is interpreted as part of it.

Comment: Is that really a problem ? Some code is generated by Certbox.

Comment: I'd say every directive needs to be terminated by a semi. And the fact that the warnings include contents from the following line are a pretty big indicator.

Comment: Probably relevant issues: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1033 https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/904

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot to add a `;` at the end of your `server_name`:

```
server_name example.com www.example.com
index index.html index.htm;
```

Nginx will continue reading the next line, using `index`, `index.html` and `index.html` as alternative server names.